# Kill a sequence of python processes

Tags: python, shell

I know I can kill a process at terminal by doing:

```
$ kill -9 666
```

where `666` is the `PID`.

but if I have ran *n* workers and want to kill all *n* processes, like so:

```
$ ps

  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  415 ttys000    0:00.09 -bash
 4356 ttys000    0:00.85 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4359 ttys000    0:03.69 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4360 ttys000    0:03.25 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4361 ttys000    0:03.11 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4362 ttys000    0:02.05 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4363 ttys000    0:01.47 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4364 ttys000    0:01.47 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4365 ttys000    0:01.47 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4366 ttys000    0:01.47 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4367 ttys000    0:03.11 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4368 ttys000    0:01.48 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4369 ttys000    0:01.49 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4370 ttys000    0:01.47 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4371 ttys000    0:01.48 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4372 ttys000    0:01.47 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4373 ttys000    0:02.68 /Users/me/bin/python 
 4374 ttys000    0:03.11 /Users/me/bin/python
```

is there a command to kill them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply kill all your processes based on it's name using below command:

```
pkill -9 -f <process-name>
```

For example, in your case the command will be:

```
pkill -9 -f /Users/me/bin/python
```

---

Another **alternative solution** will be to `grep` the result of `ps` command based on the CMD parameter and extract there `pid` using `awk`, and then kill those with `kill -9` as:

```
kill -9 `ps | grep <process-to-kill> | awk '{print $1}'`
```

For your case, in order to kill all the `"/Users/me/bin/python"` processes, the command will be:

```
kill -9 `ps | grep "/Users/me/bin/python" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Here, `ps | grep "/Users/me/bin/python" | awk '{print $1}'` will return you the list of all your process id as:

```
 4356 
 4359 
 ...
 4373
 4374
```

and `kill -9` will all the processes belonging to above pids.